# Is it safe to work on a server via SSH while uploading files to it via an SFTP file manager?

Tags: ssh, sftp, amazon-ec2

I'm uploading a large amount of data onto a server via SFTP, and could start setting things up in non-related areas with SSH while waiting, but I'm curious as to whether doing the two simultaneously can result in some sort of problem.

Specifically, I'm using an Amazon EC2, powered by Linux, but this can apply to any server.

**Is there nothing to worry about?**

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue. Server grade equipment/operating systems can handle multiple things going on at the same time (multiple SFTP sessions, multiple nfs and/or smb sessions, multiple ssh sessions, multiple http sessions, cron jobs, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the SSH commands you want to do are unrelated to the file upload, there won't be any trouble what so ever.

What I mean is, don't expect to import a database backup file to a database whilst the file is only 50% uploaded... but feel free to do whatever you want elsewhere whilst a file is being uploaded.